# i am adding Simply Google map on my ridder app but when add CameraPosition on my map there is a Error undefined Cameraposition class how i slove it?

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps, dart, maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfGMa.png)

i am adding Simply Google map on my ridder app but when add CameraPosition on my map there is a Error undefined CameraPosition class how i slove it?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Paste the text here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a variable of type CameraPosition first.

```
static final CameraPosition _kLakeLocation = CameraPosition( //defined here
      bearing: 192.8334901395799,
      target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
      tilt: 59.440717697143555,
      zoom: 19.151926040649414);
```

Now refer it in your GoogleMap widget, like this:

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _kLakeLocation, // assigned here
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
),
```

Comment: i did it but still error undefined Cameraposition class

Comment: @RafaqatAli Have you imported this at the top of main_screen.dart? 
**import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';**

If you already did that, please share the entire code so I can take a look.

Comment: how i share code